# How do i send an ARP request in C# and which library to use

Tags: c#, network-programming, arp, sniffing

I'm trying to develop a software that perform a "man in the middle" attack, and for that I need to send false ARP requests.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to spoof [ARP *replies*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing). [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) is a Link Layer (L2) protocol. To spoof packets at this layer from user mode requires using [Raw Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket) (as it is usually the TCP/IP stack in the kernel who takes care of this).

In other words, you're not going to do it on Windows in C# with any sort of common / sane mechanism.

The [`SendARP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Win32 API call is available, but it is only there for this legitimate purpose:

> ... sends an Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) request to obtain the physical address that corresponds to the specified destination IPv4 address

(There's a reason these things are not trivial.)