# C# Best approach for finding all active IP addresses in a LAN

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce, tcp

**Scenario:** 
Developing an application targeting a Win CE 5.0 powered device. The application is being developed using .NET Compact Framework 3.5 (C#).

**Question:**
Just like when you connect a computer to a LAN and you can see all the other active computers and their respective IP Address, we would like to implement something similar in our application where only the IP Addresses will be listed.

Considering that it is an existent Windows feature, I guessed it would be possible to easily implement in out application. What's the best approach considering my scenario?

Comment: If present I'd go with ActiveDirectory and IP scanning for anything else.

Comment: just so you know, most of the net view type of functionality is based on NetBIOS, which is horribly flaky. Any subnetting in absence of routing can very well prevent you from being able to see any ip addresses on the network.

Answer (score 3):

First you will have to **define** what you mean by *active* IP Addresses.

A host may **block** [ICMP_ECHO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) (commonly reffered to as `ping`) but allow TCP, UDP etc. connections on specific ports.

Depending on what type of service you require of your hosts you could

- send `ICMP_ECHO` requests to all the IP Addresses in your subnet.

  **-** To calculate the IP range of your `subnet` you may want to use the [address space bitmask](https://service.real.com/help/library/guides/helixuniversalserver/htmfiles/bitmask.htm)

  **-** For ICMP request you could also use a [broadcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address) address. But most hosts do **not respond** to broadcast requests in order to prevend flooding.
- attempt to open connections on specific TCP ports (again on the whole ip range)
- ask your router to provide you with a list of hosts using it via [dns query](https://superuser.com/questions/367969/how-can-i-direct-a-query-to-specific-dns-server)
- send [arp requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060648/how-do-i-send-an-arp-request-in-c-sharp-and-which-library-to-use) to an ethernet broad cast address

Essentially there are too many ways to get a list of hosts in a specific ip range or subnet to give a general answer.

First you need to define what you need that host list for.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function that ping on about 20 or more IPAdresses going from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.20 and call it in different threads with defferent ofssets exmple :
one going from 192.168.1.1 
other one going from 192.168.1.21
.......
call them on defferent threads but dont call them a lot it would slow down the CPU and maybe freez the computer